# How can I set search criteria from user input?

Tags: html, google-sheets, api-design

I need help with a spreadsheet query where the search criteria can be set from a user input.  I have changed the spreadsheet key because it is confidential information but the code works if I manually type in the actual number for MY VARIABLE (shown right after the CONTAINS%20%27).

What I need help with is the code that will make id entered by a user to take the place of MY VARIABLE in the query below it.  Can anyone help?

```
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Text Here' />
<input type='button' onclick='javascript:changeText2()' value='Click here after you enter your Skyward Password'/>
Click on link to see your PRIDE info : <a href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20B%2C%20C%2C%20D%2C%20F%20WHERE%20D%20CONTAINS%20%27MY_VARIABLE%27&key=xxxxxgoogle spreadsheet keyFT7mL4DLX1xzeDsnzsbZG5jp4ZcWAOxU&gid=0" id=lnk>Click her for PRIDE info</a> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

first: Doesn't use javascript:

```
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Click here after you enter your Skyward Password'/>
```

It will output and error if you write: id=Ink instead of id="Ink"

```
Click on link to see your PRIDE info : <a href="" id="Ink">Click her for PRIDE info</a> <br>
```

And now the code:

```
function changeText2(){
  var ink = document.getElementById('Ink');
  ink.href = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20B%2C%20C%2C%20D%2C%20F%20WHERE%20D%20CONTAINS%20%27" +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('userInput').value)+ "%27&key=xxxxxgoogle spreadsheet keyFT7mL4DLX1xzeDsnzsbZG5jp4ZcWAOxU&gid=0"
}
```

encodeURIComponent is used to escape the string.
Simple, or?

Comment: Thanks, sadly it didn't work.
This is the code I tried to embed with the key to my sample spreadsheet.
function changeText2(){  var ink = document.getElementById('Ink');  ink.href = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20B%2C%20C%2C%20D%2C%20F%20WHERE%20D%20CONTAINS%20%27" +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('userInput').value)+ "%27&key=1LUkEwP-HEIFdYZSqwHvKgYHWqrP1f6rGXm0yLFlBE44&gid=0"}

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUkEwP-HEIFdYZSqwHvKgYHWqrP1f6rGXm0yLFlBE44/edit#gid=127431008

Comment: Here is a link to my sample data spreadsheet.  Thanks in advance.                https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUkEwP-HEIFdYZSqwHvKgYHWqrP1f6rGXm0yLFlBE44/edit#gid=127431008

Comment: Maybe I should just describe what I want to do and see if there is a better way of doing this.  From my google webpage I want a student to enter their password and have the API language query to create a html display of just their information from the sample web page listed above.